# Not showing two columns using webkit-column-count

Tags: css

I am trying to show multiple images in two column layout using CSS.

```css
.photos-two-column {
  /* Prevent vertical gaps */
  line-height: 0;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-gap: 0px;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 0px;
}

.photos-two-column img {
  /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<section class="photos-two-column">
  <img src='https://picsum.photos/200/300'>
  <img src='https://picsum.photos/210/310'>
</section>
```

I was expecting this to show single image each in two columns.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For columns to work, you need to limit the height of the container - otherwise, how is the browser supposed to know where you want one column to end, and have it start a new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell you've put two images in the same section and so it'll add them into the same column. By putting them in their own seperate sections I've created the two bar column look you wanted....

Snippet below:

```css
.photos-two-column {
  /* Prevent vertical gaps */
  line-height: 0;
  -webkit-column-count: 1;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
  -moz-column-count: 1;
  -moz-column-gap: 0px;
  column-count: 1;
  column-gap: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.photos-two-column img {
  /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<section class="photos-two-column">
  <img src='https://picsum.photos/200/300'>
</section>
<section class="photos-two-column">
  <img src='https://picsum.photos/210/310'>
</section>
```

You could also create a two column look with a table (not recommended) but here's a fiddle:

```css
img {
  /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
  width: 200px !important;
  height: 200px !important;
  border: none;
  display:block;
}

table {
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://media.mnn.com/assets/images/2018/04/sunset_through_oak_tree.jpg.653x0_q80_crop-smart.jpg" alt="Serious cat"></td>
    <td><img src="https://www.royalparks.org.uk/_media/images/the-green-park/trees/Trees-in-The-Green-Park.JPG/w_1200.jpg" alt="Cute cat"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTN-UGkcSneCbQ9LokQwT61YBcPWLJZO282mlJodcwbCFIN4ZaS&s" alt="Serious cat"></td>
    <td><img src="https://media.mnn.com/assets/images/2018/04/sunset_through_oak_tree.jpg.653x0_q80_crop-smart.jpg" alt="Serious cat"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://www.royalparks.org.uk/_media/images/the-green-park/trees/Trees-in-The-Green-Park.JPG/w_1200.jpg" alt="Cute cat"></td>
    <td><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTN-UGkcSneCbQ9LokQwT61YBcPWLJZO282mlJodcwbCFIN4ZaS&s" alt="Serious cat"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Alternatively you can create a two column layout with styled `div` elements. This is my most recommended format of the three:

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  border: none;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://media.mnn.com/assets/images/2018/04/sunset_through_oak_tree.jpg.653x0_q80_crop-smart.jpg" alt="Serious cat">
    <img src="https://www.royalparks.org.uk/_media/images/the-green-park/trees/Trees-in-The-Green-Park.JPG/w_1200.jpg" alt="Cute cat">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTN-UGkcSneCbQ9LokQwT61YBcPWLJZO282mlJodcwbCFIN4ZaS&s" alt="Serious cat">
    <img src="https://media.mnn.com/assets/images/2018/04/sunset_through_oak_tree.jpg.653x0_q80_crop-smart.jpg" alt="Serious cat">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.royalparks.org.uk/_media/images/the-green-park/trees/Trees-in-The-Green-Park.JPG/w_1200.jpg" alt="Cute cat">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTN-UGkcSneCbQ9LokQwT61YBcPWLJZO282mlJodcwbCFIN4ZaS&s" alt="Serious cat">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you guide on how is it different from the example here? If I show 3 or 4 images using the same method it works good. https://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/

Comment: Sure, this method (without including Javascript.) can only produce the pattern of two images per colum before breaking into the next column. I will edit my answer to show you two more ways of producing a two column image layout that you can decide the format of. :)

Comment: @HardikShah There we go, I've added two more solutions to your problem. The best one is the last option as it's the easiest to adjust if you need to change the page layout in future!